# Memory corruption due to mismatched compiler directives in library vs. EXE projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a library `StudentModelLib` in which `CStudentModeler` is the main class in the library. It has a logging option that I made conditional on whether `PRETTY_LOG` is enabled. If only if `PRETTY_LOG` is enabled do I include the `CPrettyLogger`, initialize it (later), and/or actually log things.

Another project in the same solution, `StudentModel2`, statically links to `StudentModelLib`. It includes `StudentModeler.h` from the library and instantiates `CStudentModeler` at runtime.

How to set up the weirdness:

1. Set `PRETTY_LOG` inside the library in the project's preprocessor definitions
2. *Unset* `PRETTY_LOG` in the EXE project
3. Compile the entire solution, which builds the library, then the EXE

The weirdness starts when `CStudentModeler` is instantiated within the code for the executable. At that point, the debugger seems confused about which version of `CStudentModeler` it should be using and hovering over variables in the IDE leads to really confusing results. When the EXE runs, it also has memory corruption that shows up.

My hypothesis is that the compiled library's `CStudentModeler` has a `prettyLogger` member, but the compiled EXE uses the .h file with the directive disabled and it assumes `CStudentModeler` does *not* have a `prettyLogger` member. I'm guessing the memory corruption occurs because the library and the EXE have different definitions for where class's member variables live on the heap.

My questions are as follows:

1. Have I correctly identified the problem?
2. Is it possible to have library features be optional based on compiler directives but not break other projects that use that library?
3. What is the proper way to ensure that the projects using the library assume the correct enabled features based on how the library was compiled?
4. How is it that no part of the VS2010 compilation/linking process warns me about this seemingly huge bug?

For the sake of this test, `CPrettyLogger` has an empty default constructor and all other code related to it is commented out. Simply instantiating it causes the bug.

### StudentModeler.h

This is part of the library and contains the conditional member variable.

```
class CStudentModeler : public CDataProcessor2
{
   // Configuration variables
   string                  student_id;

   // Submodules
   CContentSelector        contentSelector;
   EventLog                eventLog;

#ifdef PRETTY_LOG
   CPrettyLogger           prettyLogger;      // <--- the problem?
#endif

   // Methods
   void  InitConcepts();
   void  InitLOs();

   public:
   CStudentModeler( string sm_version, string session_id, string url,
                    string db_user, string db_password, string db_name,
                    SMConfig config );

   ~CStudentModeler();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems your assessment is right on the spot.
2. Yes, it is possible. Don't make externally visible declarations depend on preprocessing directives and you should be OK. Internal stuff may be as configurable as you want, but interfaces should be set in stone. In your case the library should export an interface and a class factory. The client should either not know whether the selected instance has an additional feature, or be able to access it only through potentially fallible interface. If it fails, it's not supported.
3. If you do what I'm suggesting in (2) you shouln't need to. If you still want to, have a variable name that macro expands to `library_options_opt1_yes_opt2_no_opt3_42_...` in the library, and have the client code in the header reference it. You will have a link error in case of mismatch.
4. Thr C++ standard specifically allows the compiler not to warn you if you do such things. It's actually not really easy for the compiler. The corresponding rule is called One Definition Rule.